# find the best combination of rows in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

I need help to generate a function in Rstudio that helps me to select in a matrix of 0 and 1 the most number of rows with a single 1 per column and the most number of columns with 1.

in the following example

```
m<- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0), ncol = 3 , nrow = 5)
print(m)
```

the result would be the rows 2,3,4

Comment: What programming language?   What does this have to do with an IDE (Rstudio)?

Comment: Also, please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)   And neither is "please write some code for me".

Comment: it is unclear what you are looking for. Elaborate as to how/why rows 2,3,4 are the required results

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute-force approach (assuming you always have less columns than rows)

```
Filter(
  length,
  combn(1:nrow(m),
    ncol(m),
    function(k) {
      mat <- m[k, , drop = FALSE]
      if (all(rowSums(mat) == 1) & all(colSums(mat) == 1)) {
        return(k)
      }
    },
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4
```